# How to perform SQL batch updates to update one property in Entity Framework Core 6 C#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I have the following code to perform an update in Azure SQL table using Entity Framework

```
public class DatabaseRepo
{
    private readonly UserContext _context;
    
    public DatabaseRepo(UserContext userContext)
    {
        _context = userContext;
    }        

    public async Task BatchUpdateUsersAsync(List<User> users)
    {           
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            var entity = await _context.Users
                                       .FirstOrDefaultAsync(item => item.Id == user.Id);
            entity.StartDate = user.StartDate;

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

All I want to do update `StartDate` value of all these users. Is there a better way to do batch update?

I'm using EF Core 6

I tried this:

```
public async Task BatchUpdateUsersAsync(List<User> users)
{
        foreach (var user in users)
        {                
            var entry = _context.Set<User>().Add(user);
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

but this throws an error about some other property can't be null.

Comment: Use some [extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/). I'd recommend linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore.

Answer (score 3):

EF Core 7 introduces new bulk update features, including update and delete.
Info from Microsoft: [ExecuteUpdate and ExecuteDelete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/execute-insert-update-delete)

You can use the following:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
_context.Users
       .Where(p => p.IsActive || p.Username == "DoNotUpdateMe")
       .ExecuteUpdate(p => p.SetProperty(x => x.StartDate, x => dateTime));
      _context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: He was asking for EF Core 6

Comment: @UpenderReddy Yeah you are right. It is always good food for thought to know newer versions of frameworks will do what you are trying to accomplish. 

Thank you for pointing it out though!

Comment: you are absolutely right. but it will not full fill his requirement. knowing upcoming changes is better way of learning why we need to upgrade new version.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Attach` Updates only Required column's those are `IsModified =true` code will be as follows

```
   public async Task BatchUpdateUsersAsync(List<User> users)
    {
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            _context.Set<User>().Attach(user);
            _OSTContext.Entry(user).Property(x => x.StartDate).IsModified = true; //updates only Startdate Column
        }

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

This will be use any Entity Frame work version

Answer (score -2):

You can use the Select method for batch updates, the performance values ​​in the documentation are shared below.

[More Info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/execute-insert-update-delete)

```
public class DatabaseRepo
{
    private readonly UserContext _context;
    
    public DatabaseRepo(UserContext userContext)
    {
        _context = userContext;
    }        

    public async Task BatchUpdateUsersAsync(List<User> users)
    {           
        var entities = users.Select(async (user) => await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(item => item.Id == user.Id));
        entities.ExecuteUpdate(p => p.SetProperty(u => u.StartDate, u => DateTime.Now));
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this possible in EF Core 6?

Comment: Yes, you can. @user989988

Comment: I don't see BulkUpdate in context

Comment: In order to use the method, the package at nuget must be included in the project.

[Nuget package adress](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EFCore) @user989988

Comment: Edited to work without using nuget. @user989988